# PHP combining multiple variable

Tags: php, variables

I am new to php and I have a problem with the following code:

```
$ID = $_POST["first_name"]
$EXT = ".html"
$DOMAIN = "blabla.com/membersarea/"
$URL =  ($DOMAIN . $ID . $EXT)
header("location: http://".$URL);
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
```

The error is on line 3:

```
$EXT = ".html"
```

So my question is: is the error because of a point in a php variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed semicolon `;` in your code. Each statements should ends with semi-colon `;`

```
<?php
  $ID = $_POST["first_name"];
  $EXT = ".html";
  $DOMAIN = "blabla.com/membersarea/";
  $URL =  ($DOMAIN . $ID . $EXT);
  header("location: http://".$URL);
?>
```

Comment: And every other line apart from the last as well.

Comment: even after `$DOMAIN = "blabla.com/membersarea/"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `;` semi-colon delimiter to say php that this is the end of this line...

```
<?php
   $ID = $_POST["first_name"];
   $EXT = ".html";
   $DOMAIN = "blabla.com/membersarea/";
   $URL =  ($DOMAIN . $ID . $EXT);
   header("location: http://".$URL);
?>
```

Also use `exit;` after `header()`

```
<?php
   $ID = $_POST["first_name"]; /* Sanitize your data, atleast use mysqli_real_escape_string()*/
   $EXT = ".html";
   $DOMAIN = "blabla.com/membersarea/";
   $URL =  ($DOMAIN.$ID.$EXT); /* Also don't leave any spaces here */
   header("location: http://".$URL);
   exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put semi-colon at the end of each line to tell php its the end of line and you are going to start next one.
So, in your code put semi-colon(;) in the first four lines.